# Clojure variable arguments idiom

Tags: clojure

I'm trying out Clojure using [the official guides](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions). Here's my solution to problem 8 of that link, which is to write a function `opposite` which is supposed to mimic the `complement` function:

```
(defn opposite [f] (fn [& args] (not (apply f args))))
```

For comparison, here's the source code of `complement`:

```
(defn complement
  "Takes a fn f and returns a fn that takes the same arguments as f,
  has the same effects, if any, and returns the opposite truth value."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [f] 
  (fn 
    ([] (not (f)))
    ([x] (not (f x)))
    ([x y] (not (f x y)))
    ([x y & zs] (not (apply f x y zs)))))
```

Now, my implementation seems to work in simple cases with only a couple of arguments, e.g

```
user=> (def unequal (opposite =))
#'user/unequal
user=> (unequal 1 2)
true
user=> (unequal 1 1)
false
```

So my two-part question is:

1. Is my `opposite` function equivalent to `complement`, or does it just
   look like it? I.e. are the first three cases for definite numbers of
   arguments actually necessary?
2. If they aren't necessary, is there a reason that the form of the complement 
   source code is somehow idiomatic Clojure?

Thanks in advance (and hail friendly SO!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Clojure source code breaks out the 0, 1, and 2 arg cases for efficiency purposes.  They have essentially "pre-compiled" out 3 special cases, plus one general case.

Your code is perfectly legal, and preferred unless a performance bottleneck has been measured & proven (or you are writing a compiler/library like `clojure.core`).